# Limit the number of repeats in pseudo random python list

Tags: python, random, repeat, shuffle

For a science experiment, I need to generate a pseudo-random order for administering two different tests, 10 times each. I've used this code:

```
import random
randy  = [1] * 10 + [2] * 10 
random.shuffle(randy)
```

This gives me a nicely shuffled order for testing, however I need to ensure that the max number of repeated tests is not larger than 3. In other words, don't administer the "1" test more than 3 times in a row.

Can anyone think of a good way to do this? Shuffling multiple times does not guarantee success. Any way I can robustly check the shuffled list and change it accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: So you want to avoid `1` three times in a row. That is all what you want

Comment: Or maybe 2 three times in a row, that could happen.

Comment: Yes I need to avoid more than 3 "1" or "2" tests in a row.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting problem. Naive algorithms that simply append a random element from the list, but make an exception when there are too many consecutive numbers will not work. Also, I think it is tricky to ensure that you have a uniform probability distribution across all lists that satisfy this property. Do you require the distribution to have this property?

Comment: If you require the distribution to be uniform, one way to do it is to generate all lists which satisfy your constraint and pick one randomly from them. This is obviously grossly inefficient and I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: Also, algorithms which generate a random list and then do post processing **must** have some randomness in the post processing, otherwise you won't have the uniform distribution

Comment: I wish I could just test them alternately, and not random with this constraint.  Sadly, there must be some randomness to the order of tests. I agree that trying to enforce this constraint takes away from the randomness of the process. That is why I think this is a tricky problem. I think I will have to accept non-uniform distribution for now.

Comment: @willpower2727 I think you misunderstood what I meant, I didn't say that the constraint takes away from the randomness of the process (but that is true, it reduces the entropy of the list). By a uniform probability distribution, I meant uniform across the lists which satisfy your constraint. In which case I think (but am not sure) Reut Sharabani has actually done this. I think his solution actually does yield a uniform distribution

Comment: @texasflood: For such a small problem space, precomputing the solutions is not only the simplest, but also not all that expensive. It also ensures that all the possible solutions have an equal chance of being chosen (to the extent that `random.choice` is capable). Reut Sharabani's approach doesn't produce a uniform distribution over the solutions.

Comment: Ok I really want to thank everyone who has contributed to this. I think I worded the question to sound like some high-school home work assignment. But this is for real research. I've been writing code to provide real-time biofeedback via virtual reality for stroke patients working on rehabilitating their gait (walking). I needed to figure out how to test left and right legs in a pseudo random order. So all of you have really contributed to something good, not just someone else's homework. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Y's solution makes you search the whole solution space; although this is bearable it's hardly worth doing. Instead, just sample optimistically:

```
import random

sequences = []
order = [1, 0] * 10

while len(sequences) < 10:
    random.shuffle(order)

    if order in sequences:
        continue

    sequences.append(order[:])
```

Then to remove groups of length 4, you could check with something like

```
from itertools import groupby

while len(sequences) < 10:
    random.shuffle(order)

    if order in sequences:
        continue

    if all(len(list(group)) < 4 for _, group in groupby(order)):
        sequences.append(order[:])
```

Comment: Good point. As the size of the problem gets bigger, the less practical it is to generate every possible solution. Personally, if I were taking the approach you're suggesting, I would not just get 10 total shuffles and hope that some survive. I would put the grouping test inside the loop and only append *usable* results.

Comment: @JohnY That's what I was trying to say, yes. I'll edit it since it's obviously not clear.

Comment: Thank you @Veedrac. I like this the best because it has flexibility between getting a solution that works without having to spend "larger" amounts of time computing all possible answers. I say it's more flexible because if I want to change to say, only 10 tests or to 50 tests I can easily adapt this method without having to re-compute the solution space. I will probably increase the number of samples though to get a better random pick.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an optimistic-retry strategy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import choice

def added1(lst, bank):
    if len(bank) == 0:
        return lst
    selection = choice(bank)
    lst.append(selection)
    bank.remove(selection)
    if selection == 1:
        return added11(lst, bank)
    return added2(lst, bank)

def added11(lst,bank):
    if len(bank) == 0:
        return lst
    bank.remove(2)
    lst.append(2)
    return added2(lst, bank)

def added2(lst, bank):
    if len(bank) == 0:
        return lst
    selection = choice(bank)
    lst.append(selection)
    bank.remove(selection)
    if selection == 2:
        return added22(lst, bank)
    return added1(lst, bank)

def added22(lst,bank):
    if len(bank) == 0:
        return lst
    bank.remove(1)
    lst.append(1)
    return added1(lst, bank)

def start(lst, bank):
    bank_bkp = bank[:]
    while True:
        try:
            if len(bank) == 0:
                return lst
            selection = choice(bank)
            lst.append(selection)
            bank.remove(selection)
            if selection == 1:
                return added1(lst, bank)
            return added2(lst, bank)
        except:
            # retry
            bank = bank_bkp[:]
            lst = []


print start([], [1] * 10 + [2] * 10)
```

Output:

> [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]

It is based on simple functions representing states in this automaton:
[image: automaton]

which enforces the rules, and a bank of options. If the bank of options runs out - it tries again.

It **could** potentially take a lot of time, but it doesn't:

```
print timeit.repeat('start([], [1] * 10 + [2] * 10)', setup="from __main__ import start", number=10000, repeat=3)
```

Output:

> [0.14524006843566895, 0.14585399627685547, 0.14375996589660645]

**Note**: This is recursive so a bank with over ~2000 members requires you to explicitly allow deeper recursions.

Comment: Thanks @Reut Sharabani, this is very clever. I like that you always get the desired number of tests, 10 each. I also like the use of choice() throughout. If I were to use this I might alter it slightly, since it never allows for 3 repeats. At this point I'm not sure if I care that there are max of 2 repeats.

Comment: I missed the fact that you allow 3 repeats. I may alter it later (I'm on my cellphone), although the idea is clear and not much is learned from adding the code for two more states in the automaton.

Comment: This doesn't produce a uniform distribution over the possible solutions, though. It's definitely clumpy.

Comment: @JohnY I was wondering about the uniform distribution. Why does it not produce such distribution?

Comment: My knowledge of probability is not strong enough to give you a rigorous response. I will say that I tested your approach against straight-up `random.choice` over the 8196 solutions (which only allow maximum runs of two in a row); and straight-up `random.choice` is more random. My suspicion is that it has to do with the fact that not every random choice in the automaton is equally weighted. Some choices get to effectively assign two moves (the choices that result in `added11` or `added22` are twice as "heavy" as the choices that result in `added1` or `added2`).

Comment: Yes. This effectivelymeans they get the weight of 1,1,[* from bank]. True.

Comment: @John Y How did you measure the randomness? Did you measure the entropy? I do have a strong background in probability and should be able to work out if this solution is unbiased but unfortunately I don't have the time to do this now, but I will at some point in the future

Comment: I will delete this answer if I can't get around to fix it soon.

Comment: @texasflood: Using the technique from my answer, I computed all possible binary sequences of length 20 which satisfied the requirements. Then I ran 10000 iterations of `start` followed by 10000 iterations of just `random.choice` over the possible solutions; repeated several times, then also ran 100000 iterations of each, repeated several times. Even after running 100000 iterations of `start`, with only 8196 total slots, `start` wasn't hitting all the slots, and was hitting some slots 80, 90, or even occasionally 100 times. `random.choice` was much smoother.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I can understand if you want to delete it, but personally I will be a little disappointed if you do, just because it's still a nifty technique, and maybe for some purposes it's "random enough". I pointed out the distribution issue only to make sure readers of this answer knew what they were getting, not to disparage it.

Comment: It's very biased as your tests show, so it's best to mentiin why and hiw biased it is. I have an idea on hiw to do it, but not the time.

Comment: Oh, also, kudos on the diagram! Makes it very easy to follow your logic!

Comment: @ReutSharabani I don't think it deserves deletion, it may be good enough for some applications! And perhaps with a few tweaks it could be made to work properly

Answer (score 2):

For a problem of such small size, I disagree with @texasflood's comment that precomputing all the possibilities and then just picking from among them would be grossly inefficient. In fact, the stated parameters are so small that it is very manageable to just generate all the possibilities using sheer brute force, as I'll demonstrate below.

In your particular case, you always only run 20 tests, and you only have 2 possible tests to choose from. So you know that you cannot possibly have more than 2**20 sequences, even with no other constraints. This is only 1048576 possibilities, easily manageable with today's memory.

Further, according to your problem statement, you're constrained to using 10 of one test and 10 of the other. That reduces the number of possibilities to 184756. (Using classical probability counting techniques, this is computed as 20!/(10!*10!).)

And that's before you've even eliminated the possibilities with runs of four (or more) of the same test in a row.

So, my strong recommendation is to just do the work of computing all the usable possibilities, and then use `random.choice` on this collection of possibilities.

To get you started, here's a simple loop to get all the possible sequences that contain exactly 10 zeros and 10 ones:

```
sequences = []
for n in range(2**20):
    b = bin(n)[2:].zfill(20)
    if b.count('1') == 10:
        sequences.append(b)
```

Note that the `bin` function (which requires Python 2.6 or later) generates a binary string representation of an integer, which starts with `'0b'` (thus the `[2:]` to strip it off).

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to eliminate the four-in-a-row sequences. (Hint: You can simply refine the sample code I gave above, by testing for the existence of `'1111'` or the existence of `'0000'` in the binary string. You will wind up with a total of 66486 usable sequences, quite a small number by today's standards.)

Comment: Nice work. It works for a problem of this size, but if you were doing this on a MCU, you would have problems! For a serious scientific experiment, this is the best solution.

Comment: Yes thank you @John Y. This is the most correct form of thinking on the issue. Using this method would provide the best random choice

Answer (score 0):

I would make your own shuffler since it would probably be the fastest and most elegant option:

```
randy = []

ones = [1] * 10
twos = [2] * 10

for i in range(20):
    if len(randy) > 3 and randy[i-1] == randy[i-2] == randy[i-3]:
        randy.append(ones.pop() if randy[i-1] == 1 else twos.pop())
    else:
        randy.append(random.choice([ones, twos]).pop())
```

Comment: except of course that it doesn't work... (the `ones` and `twos` "run out" of items too early... makes sense.) I'm liking this more than the other answer but it'll need to be changed to make it work, not sure how or even if it's possible.

Comment: thanks for trying, I'm flattered anyone at all thought this was worth trying to answer. Unfortunately the logic here is not quite right, I can still get more than 3 "1" or "2" tests in a row. The looping works more often if you loop like 14 times instead of 20.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't keep exactly 10 1's and 10 2's so may not be what you're after, but it goes based on the chance (currently 50% for each), and you can add new tests if needed.

```
import random
from operator import itemgetter

#randy = [ [item,amount], ... ]
randy  = [[1,10],[2,10]]

#This turns the above list into the same format of your 'randy'
itemList = [j for k in[([i[0]]*i[1])for i in randy]for j in k]  

randomList = [-1]  #This stops the check from causing problems at the start
for i in range(len(itemList)):
    while True:
        newChoice = random.choice( itemList )
        if len(set(randomList[-2:]+[newChoice]))-1: #Checks the last 2 values plus the new value aren't all the same
            randomList.append( newChoice )
            break
shuffledList = randomList[1:]
```

Comment: This is really great, I changed the part "randomList[-2:]+" to be "randomList[-3:]+" since it is ok to have 3 repeats, simply not more than 3 repeats. As you say however, it does not guarantee that I will have exactly 10 of each test. I'll keep this in mind though. I'm just grateful for the help!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I noticed that when I was trying to get it to choose exactly 10 of each, forgot to update the question since I froze python like 3 times and gave up haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version of Veedrac's answer, where you want to get only one correct list. More interesting if you want to get a sequence *on the fly*, but less if you want to avoid *sequence repetition*.

```py
from random import shuffle
from itertools import groupby

def get_binary_sequence(sequence_length, maximum_repetitions):
    order = [True, False] * int(sequence_length/2)
    while True:
        shuffle(order)
        if all(len(list(group)) <= maximum_repetitions _, group in groupby(order)):
            return order
```